# Cannot sign into Apple Mac AppStore

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

After entering my password to update apps on the MacAppStore, I get the spinning cog and have to Force-quit the AppStore app. This also happens with Xcode.

I've tried logging into a new user account, but that also will not let me log in.

I'm able to log into all accounts on another computer.

I'm on OSX 10.11.x

Has anyone else seen this? I could not find relevant questions.

Thanks

Comment: I would check the Internet accounts pane of your Mac as every computer is "formally" registered under one Apple ID, which may be causing your problems

Comment: I will . Thx, but why would I be able to use some services but not others?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. In Internet accounts, it should show all accounts used on that user. Just remove any extraneous or reconfigure your account with all and any of the services you need by checking the boxes.

Comment: hmm. when I try to access anything in Internet Accounts, I'm prompted for my iCloud password, and I get stuck again, with the spinning cog.. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Hmm... It looks like you have a problem with the "official" iCloud account. I'll post an answer with some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you may need to reconfigure your computer's iCloud. You can achieve this by reinstalling OS X. Then it would allow you to set up your iCloud account from start out. *Before beginning, I **strongly** recommend you backup your computer just in case something goes wrong*

1. Restart your Mac
2. When you hear the start up chime, hold Command ⌘+R
3. Click "Reinstall OS X"
4. Follow the instructions listed

If that doesn't work, you may need to fully erase and restore from backup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will contact Apple support before I make anymore of a mess :) as a developer, it's rather tedious to recreates all the permissions needed to run apps on devices.

Comment: Good idea. I didn't want to suggest that since it seemed like a "catch all." I hope you can solve the problem.